# ECONNREFUSED mysql nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to follow the 'tutorial' on http://www.gianlucaguarini.com/blog/push-notification-server-streaming-on-a-mysql-database/ to get accustomed to node and node+mysql. It throws an error whilst using the exact same code though:

```
C:\node\testproject>node index.js
   info  - socket.io started
{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  fatal: true }
```

I'm using usbwebserver in which i've created a database on port 8080 whilst the code is listening to 8000. So i've tried changing that one to 8000 but to no avail. The error is slightly different in doing so:

```
C:\node\testproject>node index.js
   info  - socket.io started
   warn  - error raised: Error: listen EADDRINUSE
{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  fatal: true }
```

I'm using the exact same code as the tutorial stated above. But for reference here it is:

```
var app                 = require('http').createServer(handler),
    io                  = require('socket.io').listen(app),
    fs                  = require('fs'),
    mysql               = require('mysql'),
    connectionsArray    = [],
    connection          = mysql.createConnection({
        host        : 'localhost',
        user        : 'root',
        password    : 'usbw',
        database    : 'nodejs'
    }),
    POLLING_INTERVAL = 3000,
    pollingTimer;

// If there is an error connecting to the database
connection.connect(function(err) {
  // connected! (unless `err` is set)
  console.log( err );
});

// creating the server ( localhost:8000 )
app.listen(8000);

// on server started we can load our client.html page
function handler ( req, res ) {
    fs.readFile( __dirname + '/client.html' , function ( err, data ) {
        if ( err ) {
            console.log( err );
            res.writeHead(500);
            return res.end( 'Error loading client.html' );
        }
        res.writeHead( 200 );
        res.end( data );
    });
}

/*
*
* HERE IT IS THE COOL PART
* This function loops on itself since there are sockets connected to the page
* sending the result of the database query after a constant interval
*
*/

var pollingLoop = function () {

    // Doing the database query
    var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM users'),
        users = []; // this array will contain the result of our db query

    // setting the query listeners
    query
    .on('error', function(err) {
        // Handle error, and 'end' event will be emitted after this as well
        console.log( err );
        updateSockets( err );
    })
    .on('result', function( user ) {
        // it fills our array looping on each user row inside the db
        users.push( user );
    })
    .on('end',function(){
        // loop on itself only if there are sockets still connected
        if(connectionsArray.length) {
            pollingTimer = setTimeout( pollingLoop, POLLING_INTERVAL );

            updateSockets({users:users});
        }
    });

};


// creating a new websocket to keep the content updated without any AJAX request
io.sockets.on( 'connection', function ( socket ) {

    console.log('Number of connections:' + connectionsArray.length);
    // starting the loop only if at least there is one user connected
    if (!connectionsArray.length) {
        pollingLoop();
    }

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        var socketIndex = connectionsArray.indexOf( socket );
        console.log('socket = ' + socketIndex + ' disconnected');
        if (socketIndex >= 0) {
            connectionsArray.splice( socketIndex, 1 );
        }
    });

    console.log( 'A new socket is connected!' );
    connectionsArray.push( socket );

});

var updateSockets = function ( data ) {
    // adding the time of the last update
    data.time = new Date();
    // sending new data to all the sockets connected
    connectionsArray.forEach(function( tmpSocket ){
        tmpSocket.volatile.emit( 'notification' , data );
    });
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps your port is already in use. Open you cmd and type `netstat -a`. This is for checking the ports availability.

Comment: 8080 and 80 are in use. But that's because usbwebserver is on. 8000 is not on by the looks of it